# Tensorflow crashes my system while retraining ssd_mobilenet

Tags: tensorflow, crash, deep-learning

The system configuration is as follows:

Ubuntu 16.04,
 cuda 9.1,

cudnn 7.0.5,

nvidia driver 390.30,

GTX 1050 TI gpu,

tensorflow-gpu 1.7rc1 and 1.5,

configuration file and train.py is stock from the tensorflow distribution, and
 the trained model being used is ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17.

The following is collected from the putty terminal session:

(od) gennis@AI:~/models/research$ ./train_raccoon.sh
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/dennis/.virtualenvs/od/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the retry module or similar alternatives.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/dennis/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py:228: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step

INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0

INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0

INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0

INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0

INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0

INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0

INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/dennis/.virtualenvs/od/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py:736: **init** (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession

2018-03-23 16:59:01.725435: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1355] Found device 0 with properties:

name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.455

pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0

totalMemory: 3.94GiB freeMemory: 3.89GiB

2018-03-23 16:59:01.725484: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1434] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

2018-03-23 16:59:02.090533: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:922] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:

2018-03-23 16:59:02.090592: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:928]      0

2018-03-23 16:59:02.090601: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:941] 0:   N

2018-03-23 16:59:02.090801: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1052] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3631 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /home/dennis/models/research/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17/model.ckpt

INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.

INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.

INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.

INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path temp/model.ckpt

INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.

INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0

At this point the system crashes and I have to power down the system and then power it back up(reboot).

In addition to my training data and configuration, I also used the model and data from an article by Dat Tran called "How to train your object detector with Tensorflow's object detection API" and got the same results.

I have been able to run the mnist example and other tests that show that tensorflow-gpu is working.

I am not sure what to do next.  Is there additional information I can gather to help further diagnose the problem?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: please edit the question for easy reading

Comment: Can you look at the usual crash logs to see what can be causing these crashes? (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38608/how-to-determine-why-my-computer-crashed for how)